# How to add multiple ckeditor in django template for same model field?

Tags: django, ckeditor

I have Multiple Choice Question model and answer model. For one question there are 4 answers. I need to add ckeditor in all 5 field. No problem with question field, but i can not get it work for 4 answer fields. I tried replace textarea with ckeditor but can not get image upload to work.